# Java distributed or share cache with openshift

Tags: java, openshift, hazelcast, ehcache

We develop a Java application with springboot and relational database which is deployed on Openshift 3 (min 4 pods - max 8 pods).

Some performance issue has been raised and we would like add cache system (free).
We have found some library but when we update datas on 1 pod, 3 pods aren't updated. How can we resolved it ? Can we have sharing cache between all pods / replace by high performance database ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hazelcast will make your data available across all your pods, provided the Hazelcast instance in each SpringBoot pod can find the Hazelcast instance in each other SpringBoot pod.

To do this, use the [hazelcast-kubernetes plugin](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes).

What you need to watch in the logs is the member count.
If you see a message like this:

```
Members {size:4, ver:4} [
    Member [123.45.67.89]:5701
    Member [123.456.78.9]:5701
    Member [123.45.6.789]:5701
    Member [123.45.67.89]:5701
]
```

then four pods have joined together and data sharing happens automatically. If they fail to join, then data sharing can't happen, which is probably what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Some cache are distributed, some are not. For example, the Open Source free version of EHCache is not distributed: if you update data on node X, the change won't be replicated on node Y.

On the other hand, the Open Source free version of Hazelcast IMDG is distributed. Nodes can be configured to form a cluster. At this point, you'll need to configure the network parameters.

All in all, your question is too high-level to benefit from a meaningful answer. I hope mine did at least help you understand the general issues.